# Nodejs query results don't display?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose to create data objects but I'm having trouble displaying these objects on a webpage. I added the getAllUsers query to my users.js file. I'm then using handlebars to display the list of users on my template webpage.

I have users in my table but I don't see any results. What am I missing?

Full code below. Thanks!

**Users.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  tokens: [{
    access: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }]
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
  var query = {email: email};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getAllUsers = function(callback){
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err){
      res.send('error');
      next();
    }
    res.json(users);
  });
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}
```

**Users.handlebars:**

```
<div class="main-container">
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb64 mb-xs-24">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h3>users</h3>
          <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="horizontal-tile">
              {{#each users}}
              <div class="tile-left">
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="background-image-holder">
                    <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="img/project-single-1.jpg">
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="tile-right bg-secondary">
                <div class="description">
                  <h4 class="mb8">{{this}}</h4>
                  <h6 class="uppercase">
                    Graphic Design
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

EDIT:

users.js in my routes folder:

```
// get users
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('users');
});
```

Comment: Where do you call `getAllUsers()?`. You need a route (in this context you can use http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I posted a snippet from my routes. I think this only renders the page. How can I call the actual function?

Comment: @alfredopacino ^

Comment: Your route render function has to pass your users object to the template, which would look something like `res.render('users', {users: yourUsersObj});` Which means your route needs to call the function that gets all users first before it renders the template.

Answer (score 0):

Remodel your method so it returns the Users array and not responds (it didn't have access to `res` anyway):

```
module.exports.getAllUsers = function(callback){

  return User.find({}, function(err, users) {

    return callback(err, users);

  });

}
```

Inside your `users.js` route:

```
const Models = require('/path/to/your/models');

...
...
...

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  Models.User.getAllUsers(function(err, users) {

    if(err) {
        res.send('error');
        next();
    }

    res.render('users', users);

  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Still learning node. I'm going to give this a try when I get home later. I'll accept the answer then 

Comment: Pleasure is mine, ask for any further info whenever you need it.

Comment: I got an error `Error: Cannot find module '/models/'` but I fixed it by changing `Models.User.find` to `User.find` since I already defined User as `var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);`. However I'm not getting results back. Could that be the reason why?

Comment: I don't get if you still get an error or simply got nothing. What is the response of your route?

Comment: At first I was getting that error above. Then I changed the code to fix the error but now I'm not getting any results. I don't see any errors in my console now